# Facebook like button isn't working

Tags: javascript, facebook

I wrote a simple facebook like button for my experiments so that I can integrate Facebook features in my application:
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Facebook and twitter log in</title>
  </head>

<body>
 <script>

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '843995905631867',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.2'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));




  </script>

  <div
  class="fb-like"
  data-share="true"
  data-width="450"
  data-show-faces="true">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And I got these warnings:

```
The "fb-root" div has not been created, auto-creating 
fb:like failed to resize in 45s
```

And I got a blank screen... Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the generator to get the correct code and it will work: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

You are missing some things like the url to like (data-href) and the fb-root div (which is not that important because it will get auto-created.

Comment: When I use`js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=843995905631867&version=v2.0";`, I get this error:  `GET file://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. How to fix it?

Comment: you either need to use a webserver, or you need to add http: or https: in front of the url...but you can´t just use the like button without even localhost, i guess.